# Rational multiple of a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.5011.pdf of Chi Li and Song Sun, they say that "$D$ is a smooth divisor which is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly equivalent to $−\lambda K_X$ for some $λ \in \mathbb{Q}$", and $X$ is a Fano manifold. I do not understand what is the meaning of "$\mathbb{Q}$-linearly equivalent".

In my opinion, if $L$ is linear equivalent to $-\frac{m_1}{m_2}K_X$, then we mean that $m_2 L$ is linear equivalent to $-m_1K_X$, for $m_1,m_2\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $m_1,m_2$ are prime with each other. Another question is whether $m_2$ here can be taken along all $\mathbb{Z}^+$? I wonder if $m_2$ is too large, whether there will be such line bundle $L$.

Comment: Your first "opinion" is correct. I do not understand the question that follows : you can always multiply both $m_1$ and $m_2$ by the same integer.

Comment: I have added that $\gcd (m_1,m_2)=1$.

Comment: Then $m_2$ is bounded by $\dim(X)+1$, and any value between $1$ and $\dim(X)+1$ is possible.

Comment: Why require that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are relatively prime, let me not limit myself to $-K_X$ also.  You can have a Cartier divisor that is torsion in the Picard group but not actually linearly equivalent to zero.  Then it is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly equivalent to zero but not itself linearly equivalent to zero.  $$\text{ }$$ **Definition:** on a normal variety, two $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors $F,G$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly equivalent if $mF \sim mG$ for some integer $m > 0$ so that $mF$ and $mG$ are honest Weil divisors.

Comment: I voted to leave this open because while the phrasing is confusing, this is exactly the sort of question a student might ask when they are starting research.  In particular, it isn't really a question that would be asked outside of a research environment.  I could also imagine some nice answers with nice examples.